# Python - fast way to sum outer products?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm looking for a fast way to calculate a sum of n outer products.

Essentially, I start with two matrices generated from normal distributions - there are n vectors with v elements:

```
A = np.random.normal(size = (n, v))
B = np.random.normal(size = (n, v))
```

What I'd like is to calculate the outer products of each vector of size v in A and B and sum them together.

Note that `A * B.T` doesn't work - A is of size n x v whereas B is of size v x n.

The best I can do is create a loop where the outer products are constructed, then summed later. I have it like so:

```
outers = np.array([A[i] * B[i].T])
```

This creates an n x v x v array (the loop is within the list comprehension, which is subsequently converted into an array), which I can then sum together by using `np.sum(outers, axis = 0)`. However, this is quite slow, and I was wondering if there's a vectorized function I could use to speed this up.

If anybody has any advice, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 15):

It seems to me all you need to do is change the order of the transpositions, and do `A.T * B` instead of `A * B.T`.

If that's not quite what you are after, take a look at [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which can do some very powerful voodoo. For the above example, you would do:

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->jk', A, B)
```

Answer (score 5):

Also consider `np.outer`.

```
np.array([np.outer(A, B) for i in xrange(n)]).sum(0)
```

although `np.einsum` suggested by @Jamie is the clear winner.

```
In [63]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ik->jk', A, B)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.61 us per loop

In [64]: %timeit np.array([np.outer(A[i], B[i]) for i in xrange(n)]).sum(0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 169 us per loop
```

and, to be sure, their results are identical:

```
In [65]: np.testing.assert_allclose(method_outer, method_einsum)
```

But, as an aside, I do not find that `A.T * B` or `A * B.T` broadcast successfully.

Comment: He is multiplying `np.matrix` objects, not `np.ndarray`s. `A * B.T` is then equivalent to `np.dot(A, B.T)`, and `A.T * B` to `np.dot(A.T, B)`. It should clock very, very close to `np.einsum`.

Comment: +1 for having a nice comparison between the two methods